# Installation needs 4.4GB but only have two 3.5GB SSD

Tags: 11.10, installation

The Ubuntu 11.10 install states it needs 4.4GB. The system has only two 3.5GB SSD. What next?

Comment: When chosing the mount points.. put some directories on one drive and some on the other drive.. or use a lighter -buntu or get a bigger ssd

Comment: @UriHerrera Maybe you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem. Check this out:
http://gobitech.blogspot.com/2011/06/install-ubuntu-1104-on-asus-eee-pc-701.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a lighter version of Ubuntu, or does it have to be Ubuntu?

As for Ubuntu, you would have to be selective with what you install from the basic package, which the regular install iso does not really provide, so the alternate CD could work. I did not find a quote for Ubuntu, but Xubuntu also requires 4.4 Gb with a regular install, but on the Xubuntu page they write that [Xubuntu install with the alternate CD](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) only requires 2Gb of free space on the medium on wich you wish to run the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use device mapper [FakeRAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) or Linux [software RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) to make your root file system span across the two ssds. Fakeraid works out of the box with Ubuntu, if your BIOS supports it. For Software RAID you need to use the alternate CD (afaik). I don't know if you actually get a performance gain with either of these two methods of software RAID when using ssds, nevertheless, it should solve your hard disk space problems.